# android emulator hangs while running selenium script

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to test an android web app. My test is running fine initially but hangs at particular point. It selects the first text field on the web page and writes the values while in zoom-in mode but it hangs at this point and does not select the second text field. Where am I going wrong?

My code is as follows:

public void testRegister() throws Exception
{

```
            driver.get("file:///android_asset/www/aboutus.html");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div/ul/li[2]")).click();
    List<WebElement> w1=driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
    System.out.println(w1.size());
    for(int i=0;i<w1.size();i++)
    {
    System.out.println("************");
          System.out.println(i + w1.get(i).getAttribute("id") +"*****" + w1.get(i).getAttribute("name"));

    }

    for(WebElement option:w1)
    {
          String str=option.getAttribute("id");

          if(str.equals("name"))
          {
                 option.click();
                 option.sendKeys("Vaishali");
          }

          else if(str.equals("dateofbirth"))
          {
                 option.click();
                 option.sendKeys("28-09-1991");
          }

          else if(str.equals("club"))
          {
                 option.click();
                 option.sendKeys("Manchester United");
          }

          else if(str.equals("username"))
          {
                 option.click();
                 option.sendKeys("vishchan");
          }
          else if(str.equals("password"))
          {
                 option.click();
                 option.sendKeys("vishchan");
          }
          else if(str.equals("sendbutton"))
          {
                 option.click();

          }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the id can be '' and it'l return null value
2. in the list of elements can be hidden element with the same id
   for more reasons please post stack trace.
   Best Regards Taras